# PHP: Crop file/directory path

Tags: php, path, split, crop

I have a long path like this - `/home/user/www/domain.net/public_html/system/dir/file.php`, and I want crop this to get something like - `/system/dir/file.php`.

Now I am using this code:

```
$filename = str_replace(array('\\', '/'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filename);
$filename = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_slice(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filename), -3, 3));
```

And it works, but I think there is a better solution.. Anyone know?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you don't know a certain count of directories in your result, you have to deal with something like your sample. Alternate way is regex

Comment: Wouldn't a mod_rewrite do the job?

Comment: @Fred No, because it's not a url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other solution:

```
$filename = '/home/user/www/domain.net/public_html/system/dir/file.php';
explode($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $filename);
$filename = end($filename);
```

Comment: You should write in your question that you're trying to find a path relative from `DOCUMENT_ROOT` - that's not the same as searching path in common case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex instead. See this sample:

```
$sFileName  = '/home/user/www/domain.net/public_html/system/dir/file.php';
$iCropCount = 3;
$sResult    = preg_replace('#.*?((\/[^\/]+){'.$iCropCount.'})$#', '$1', $sFileName));
//var_dump($sResult);
```

Operations with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` are omitted (since main sense of sample above are not in them)

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need the web directory. So you can explode with `/public_html` as it is always going to be there.

E.g :

```
$filename = '/home/user/www/domain.net/public_html/system/dir/file.php';
$path = explode('/public_html', $filename);
echo $path[1];
```